# This expression is not callable using navigation in React Native TS

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm getting this error when trying to define `type Nav` for navigation function:

```
type Nav = {
  navigate: {
    name: string;
    params: {
      useBack: boolean;
    };
  };
};

const InfoLink = ({
  componentName,
  title,
}: {
  componentName: string;
  title: string;
}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<Nav>();

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={styles.linkRoot}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate({ name: componentName, params: { useBack: true } })
      }
    >
      <View style={styles.linkContainer}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.linkText}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
        
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
export default InfoLink;
```

I tried looking for solution, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thx.

Comment: Please share the Nav type definition

Comment: Sorry, edited question, it's on top of the code now. Thx